# ArrayStoreException on 2D Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java-8

I am trying to fill a `Object[][]` array with `Object[]`like you would add rows to a table. But all I get is a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` at the line `data[resultSet.getRow() - 1]= mailbox;`.
Whare am I worng?
The SQL part is working

```
public static Object[][] getMailboxes() {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Object[][] data = null;
    try {
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(GET_MAILBOX, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        statement.execute();
        resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        resultSet.last();
        data = new String[resultSet.getRow()][7];
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
        Object[] mailbox = new Object[7];
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                System.out.println(i+" column of row "+resultSet.getRow());
                if (0 == i) {
                    mailbox[i] = resultSet.getInt(i + 1);
                } else if (6 == i || 5 == i) {
                    mailbox[i] = resultSet.getBoolean(i + 1);
                } else {
                    mailbox[i] = resultSet.getObject(i + 1);
                }
            }
            data[resultSet.getRow() - 1]= mailbox;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You have defined `data` as an array of strings. Therefore, you cannot store an Int or Boolean into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
data = new String[resultSet.getRow()][7];
```

to

```
data = new Object[resultSet.getRow()][7];
```

since you are attempting to store in this array objects which are not `String`s, so they can't be stored in a `String[][]` array.

Comment: Oh. That's an embarrassing mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [ArrayStoreException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) it seems like you are storing the wrong type into your array variable.
Try to Declare your array as an array of Strings, i. e.

```
String[][] data = null;
```

Apart from that, you could move the return statement into your try block in order to declare your result variables inside that block. If your try block fails, you can simply `return null` anyway.